# Using MatLab 'Union' function in a loop

Tags: matlab, loops, union

Considering a MatLab struct, I have a loop over fieldnames as follow:

```
scenario = fieldnames(myStruct)
for scenarioidx = 1:length(scenario)
    scenarioname = scenario{scenarioidx};
    category = fieldnames(myStruct.(scenarioname))
    for categoryidx = 1:length(category)
        categoryname = category{categoryidx};
        entity = fieldnames(myStruct.(scenarioname).(categoryname))
    end
end
```

This loop returns me entities for each categories. Now, I would like to combine all those entities in one vector. I tried to used the 'union' function as follow:

```
scenario = fieldnames(myStruct)
for scenarioidx = 1:length(scenario)
    scenarioname = scenario{scenarioidx};
    category = fieldnames(myStruct.(scenarioname))
    for categoryidx = 1:length(category)
        categoryname = category{categoryidx};
        allEntity = {}
        entity = fieldnames(myStruct.(scenarioname).(categoryname))
        combo_entity = union (allEntity, entity)
    end
end
```

Unfortunately, this is just returning the same results as previously and not combine anything.
Does anyone has any ideas about how to implement the union function in such a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
struct_entities = structfun(@struct2cell, myStruct, 'UniformOutput', false);
  cell_entities = struct2cell(struct_entities);
   all_entities = unique(vertcat(cell_entities{:}));
```

The idea is to:

- retrieve the entities and give up the category names;
- give up the scenario names too, because they're not needed;
- assemble the accumulated entities in a single cell array.

If the use of union is required, then the code may be rewritten as:

```
all_entities = {};

scenarios = fieldnames(myStruct);
for si = 1:numel(scenarios)
        categories = fieldnames(myStruct.(scenarios{si}));
        for ci = 1:numel(categories)
                entities = fieldnames(myStruct.(scenarios{si}).(categories{ci}));
                all_entities = union(all_entities, entities);
        end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you this does the job! unfortunately I need to implement the union function in this loop!

Comment: @steve I don't understand. When you say you want to *implement* `union`, you mean you want to define the function, or just use the standard one? `union` is a standard function, and is related to set union. It works only on numeric arrays, or cell arrays of strings. Are all `entity` things numbers, strings, or something else?

Comment: I just need to use the standard **union** function. While running my **fieldnames** loop, then **entity** are n x 1 cell.

Comment: @steve `union` doesn't work with cell arrays, unless they have only strings inside. Otherwise it will throw an error. Is this your case?

Comment: Indeed, the cells array contains strings. By the way, your solution, is a really nice workaround, Thanks!

Comment: @steve I added some code that I think it implements what you want. Also, I didn't notice that the entities are actually struct names, not struct values.